# How can I delete an item from array with a button in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
List{
    ForEach(files, id:\.self){ file in
        HStack{
            Text((file.path as NSString).lastPathComponent)
            Button(action: files.remove(at:files.firstIndex(of: file)!), label: {
                Text("Delete")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I have a view with a list in it that shows all the files user chose to process. I need to delete the corresponding file from the array when the button on the list is clicked. Right now its giving me the error "Cannot convert value of type 'URL' to expected argument type '() -> Void'". How can I fix it?

Comment: Wrap the action in brackets. It’s a closure.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez can you post your comment as an answer so the OP can accept it? That way others can tell that the question has a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button action will be wrap with a brackets. As already @EmilioPelaez already mention on the comment. Here is the implemented code.

```
Button(action: {
        files.remove(at:files.firstIndex(of: file)!)
    }, label: {
        Text("Delete")
 })
```

Comment: But this is exactly what @EmilioPelaez said.

Comment: Yes I already mention @EmilioPelaez on my answer. And this is the implementation.

Comment: @aheze that's alright! I'm here to help people, not for the points. Faysal thanks for making my comment into an answer!